# What exactly are these questions asking?

Tags: c, tabstop

I am reading the C programming textbook by Dennis Ritchie and Brian Kernighan. I finished the first chapter and stumbled across these questions that I'm not sure I'm interpreting correctly. Specifically, in Exercise 1-20, what does the authors mean when they say "Assume a fixed set of tab stops, say every *n* columns." I am also only trying to use the content presented in chapter 1 which includes: simple arrays, functions, symbolic constants, getchar(), putchar() and printf().

[Screenshot of questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUtwW.jpg)

Comment: I take it you don't understand tab stops? Like in a word processor or text editor?

Comment: @NickODell Yes that is exactly what I was looking for. I was inserting a fixed number of spaces for each tab, not considering other characters that are in the current column. I just felt like I was missing something and I was. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you should convert each tab (`'\t'`, or `0x09` on ASCII-based machines) into a non-zero number of spaces that brings the cursor to the next multiple of *n*.

For example,

Input:

```
  +---+----+------ Tabs
  |   |    |
ab␉cde␉fghi␉j␊
             |
             +---- Line Feed
```

Output: (The ruler is just for reference)

```
|...|...|...|...|...   n=4
ab  cde fghi    j␊
```